# 400 error from controller

Tags: angularjs

```
        function remove() {
        var result = confirm("delete?");
        if (result) {
            blockUI.start();
            userService.delete(vm.user).then(function (resp) {
                if (resp.result == "00") {
                    toastr.success(resp.message, "result");


                    vm.linkList();
                    //removeGrid();
                    vm.search();
                } else {
                    throw resp.message;
                }
            }, function (errResp) {
                throw errResp;
            }).catch(function (errResp) {
                errResp = errResp || "HTTP error";
                toastr.error(errResp, "error", { closeButton: true });
            }).finally(function () {
                blockUI.stop();
            });
        }
    }
```

The information will does not get deleted.

> error:"Bad Request"
>   exception:"org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException"
>       message:"Required String parameter 'id' is not present"
>       path:"/api/user/delete"
>       status:400
>       timestamp:1489648924119

Answer (score 0):

```
Required String parameter 'id' is not present" path:"/api/user/delete
```

Which means you did not pass required id param with your request .. Please check your  `userService.delete` service . The error is there .

Comment: (function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('trip.services').service('userService', userService);

    function userService($http, $q, CrudService) {
        var url = {
            queryUrl: "/trip-api/user/search",
            viewUrl: "/trip-api/user/find",
            saveUrl: "/trip-api/user/save",
            deleteUrl: "/trip-api/user/delete"
        };

        var userService = new CrudService(url);
        
        return userService;
    }

})(angular);

What's the problem?

Comment: the problem is on userService.delete(vm.user) method vm.user might be null or missing check that

Comment: ID: 09AD3A5B983249B49664F028B572D0D4 I think you should come out like this. 09AD3A5B983249B49664F028B572D0D4 I can only get out of this way. What should I do to fix the code?

Answer (score 0):

Check in user userService delete method

```
  var app = angular.module('app', []);
  app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, userService) {
    $scope.deleteUser = function(id) {
      userService.deleteUser(id);
    }
  });
  app.service('userService', function($scope) {
    this.deleteUser = function(id) {
      // api call here
      //$http.delete(id);
    }
    return this;
  });
```

Weather you are able to pass it to the api id or not, so that you will came to know where you are missing to add it either in controller or in service.

Comment: ID: 09AD3A5B983249B49664F028B572D0D4

I think you should come out like this.

09AD3A5B983249B49664F028B572D0D4

I can only get out of this way.
What should I do to fix the code?